# How can I use the output of an external command as an argument to tabnew?

Tags: bash, vim

In my `.bashrc`, I have the following short script to get the current date.

```
D(){ date +'%F'; }
```

In my `.vimrc`, I have the following two lines to make it so that I can use this function.

```
set shell=bash\ --login
set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

I have tested that the function works in `vim`, by verifying that the following command puts the current date into the buffer.

```
:r !D
```

However, what I would like to do is to use the output of this bash function as an argument to `tabnew` so I can open a file named by the current date in a new tab.

```
:tabnew !D
```

Unfortunately, the behavior of this command is to create a new tab with the literal filename `!D` isntead of the output.

How can I get the output of the external command as an argument to `tabnew` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backtick expansion can be used to insert the output of external commands in Vim commands, generally as arguments:

```
:tabnew `date +'\%F'`
```

or:

```
:tabnew `D`
```

See `:help backtick-expansion`.